# A function is changing wrong variable value

Tags: javascript

My function is something like this:

```
function sortThis(board) {
    tempBoard = board; 
    var moves = []
    for(var i = 0; i < board.length;i++)
    {
        if(tempBoard[i] == "X")
        {
            tempBoard[i] = "Z";
            moves.push(i);
        }
     }
      return moves;

}
```

But this code is changing the value of `board` variable when i change `tempBoard` value at line 8.

Why??? This bug wasted my 2 days.

Comment: Is it normal that your `return` statement is in the `for` loop ?

Comment: Assigning an array value to another variable does not make a copy of the array. Both variables are pointing to the same single array, so an update to one is an update to the other.

Comment: And probably should be `tempBoard[i] = "Z";`

Comment: Maybe you should try to copy it with `Array.from()` so you have another array. But @Pointy is totally right. Just try something like `var a = b = 5 ; a++; console.log(a,b)` a would be 6 and b remains 5. BUT if you do something like `var a = b = []; a.push("yolo"); console.log(a,b)` a AND b will be references of the same array

Comment: if board only contains strings, change `tempBoard = board` to `tempBoard = board.slice()` so that you copy the array.

Comment: @Zyigh Sorry, I put it there by mistake. @

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a bug. In JavaScript, Arrays and Objects are copied by reference and not by value, so the following behavior is normal and expected :

```js
a = [3];
b = a;
a.push(5);
console.log(b);
```

In your case as `tempBoard = board`, every modification to `tempBoard` will also affect `board`.
If you want to copy by value an array, you can do this for instance :

```js
a = [3];
b = [...a];
a.push(5);
console.log(b);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to copy the one array to another , so you have to clone the one .

There are multiple ways to do it , like `tempBoard = Object.assign([], board)`

check this [link](https://www.briangonzalez.org/post/copying-array-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

When you do `tempBoard = board`, you are just creating a new way to access to the data behind the `board` variable. It's called a `pointer`. So when you modify `tempBoard` data; it will modify the `board` data.

---

**Reproduction of the problem**

```js
function sortThis(board) {
  tempBoard = board;

  var moves = []

  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (tempBoard[i] === 'X') {
      tempBoard[i] = 'Z';

      moves.push(i);
    }
  }
  
  return moves;
}


const arr1 = ['X', 'Y'];

sortThis(arr1);

console.log(arr1);
```

---

**One of the soluce would be to perform a copy of board data instead of creating a pointer to it**

```js
function sortThis(board) {
  const tempBoard = [
    ...board,
  ];

  const moves = []

  for (var i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
    if (tempBoard[i] === 'X') {
      tempBoard[i] = 'Z';

      moves.push(i);
    }
  }

  return moves;
}


const arr1 = ['X', 'Y'];

sortThis(arr1);

console.log(arr1);
```

---

**Easier, you can create a new array from the first one using the Array.map() function**

```js
function sortThis(board) {
  return board.map(x => x === 'X' ? 'Z' : x);
}


const arr1 = ['X', 'Y'];

const arr2 = sortThis(arr1);

console.log(arr1);

console.log(arr2);
```